# How do I get zsh tab completion to "vi **/foo<TAB>" to match and complete the first file matching "foo*" anywhere under the current directory?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, tab-completion, globbing

How do I get zsh tab completion to `cat **/foo<TAB>` to match and complete the first file matching `foo*` in any subdirectory under the current directory?

For example, do this while inside a fresh test directory: (again, this is zsh)

```
% mkdir aaa bbb ccc
% touch aaa/foo bbb/foo ccc/foo
% cat **/f<TAB>
```

What I want when I hit `<TAB>` on that last line is for my screen to end up looking like this:

```
% cat aaa/foo_                 # filled in the first match; "_" is the cursor
aaa/foo  bbb/foo  ccc/foo      # and here is the list of all matches
```

I tried `setopt GLOB_COMPLETE`, but that didn't do what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.zshrc` file (or paste it into the command line, to try it out):

```
# Load Zsh's new completion system.
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit

# Bind Tab to complete-word instead of 
# expand-or-complete. This is required for 
# the new completion system to work 
# correctly.
bindkey '^I' complete-word

# Add the _match completer.
# We add it after _expand & _complete, so it 
# will get called only once those two have 
# failed.
# _match_ completes patterns only, which 
# _expand can do, too, (which is why we call 
# _match_ only when _expand & _complete 
# fail), but _match adds an extra * at the 
# cursor position. Without that, the pattern 
# **/f would not match {aaa,bbb,ccc}/foo
zstyle ':completion:*' completer \
    _expand _complete _match _ignored

# Let all possible completions for a partial 
# path be listed, rather than just the first 
# one.
zstyle ':completion:*' list-suffixes true
```

Then, when you type `cat **/f` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you will get the following output:

```
% cat aaa/foo
aaa/foo  bbb/foo  ccc/foo
**/f
```

Documentation:

- [`compinit`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Use-of-compinit)
- [`_match`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fmatch)
- [`list-suffixes`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-list_002dsuffixes_002c-completion-style)

See also: [A User's Guide to the Z-Shell: Completion, old and new](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html)

Comment: Cool, that works! I would really appreciate it if you add some explanation to your code, possible citing documentation. Particularly the longest line. This completion stuff is gnarly so I commend you!

Comment: Alright, I added plentiful code comments and links to the documentation. Good enough to accept the answer? 

Comment: Very much appreciated. Bounty awarded. Up to OP to accept the answer.